# Ignore lock-nodes when calling getChildren on a Zookeeper node

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

When I call getChildren() on a Zookeeper node with curator, is there a way to ignore child nodes that represent a lock?

I want to read all children with their data of one specific node. Therefore, I first call getChildren() and iterate over the returned List and call getData() on each such child. To avoid that the children are changing in between I foremost require an InterProcessMutex. Unfortunately, the list of children also contains this mutex.

```
InterProcessMutex mutex = new InterProcessMutex(client, parentNodePath);

mutex.acquire();

try {
  List<String> children = client.getChildren().forPath(parentNodePath);

  for (String child : children) {
    // do something
    // ignore the lock-node
  }

} finally {
  mutex.release();
}
```

Is there a smarter way to do that? Or to just ignore the lock-node?

Comment: Anyhow, this does not work even if I manually filter out the lock-children. This hangs up after 1-2 times of creating a node with different clients. Maybe I am running into an endless loop because acquiring and releasing a lock this way triggers the getChildren-watchers on all other clients, that also try to acquire a mutex and so on. When I remove the mutex, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different base for the lock nodes, this way the actual data won't get mixed with the lock data. Locks don't have to know what they are locking so there is no need to give lock mechanism the same parent base.

```
InterProcessMutex mutex = new InterProcessMutex(client, "/lock-base/lock-");
```

and then do the rest the same way was you did

```
mutex.acquire();

try {
  List<String> children = client.getChildren().forPath(parentNodePath);

  for (String child : children) {
    // do something
    // no need to worry about lock nodes
  }

} finally {
  mutex.release();
}
```

Just make sure you use the same lock node base for all of the applications trying to access parentNodePath and you're good.